# disable radio buttons in laravel 8

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am working on carwash project as my semester project in Laravel 8. I used radio buttons as time slots. How to disable the radio buttons which are already booked by the customers?

Answer (score 0):

Give the radio button the attribute `disabled` when it matches your needs.

```html
<!-- Disabled -->
<input id="radio" name="radio" type="radio" disabled>

<!-- Not disabled -->
<input id="radio" name="radio" type="radio">

<!-- With blade condition -->
<input id="radio" name="radio" type="radio" {{ $condition ? 'disabled' : '' }}>
```